# How to connect to RedisGraph using Java JRedisGraph client

Tags: redisgraph

The JRedisGraph documentation doesn't provide example on how to connect to the instance (IP, Port). 
https://github.com/RedisGraph/JRedisGraph

Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Checkout the RedisGraph overloaded constructors.

`public RedisGraph(String host, int port)`

See: https://www.javadoc.io/doc/com.redislabs/jredisgraph/2.0.0-rc3/index.html